# What is the point of the comma operator when a tuple only has one entry in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

This section of code is taken from one of the [Pytorch tutorials](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/pytorch_with_examples.html), I have just removed the non-essential parts so it doesn't error out and added some print statements. The question I have is why the two print statements I provided have slightly different results? Is this a tuple with nothing in the second half of it? I am confused by the comma without anything after it before the assignment operator.

```
import torch

class MyReLU(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        return input.clamp(min=0)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        print("ctx ", ctx.saved_tensors)
        print("inputs ", input)
        grad_input = grad_output.clone()
        grad_input[input < 0] = 0
        return grad_input

relu = MyReLU.apply
relu = MyReLU.apply
y_pred = relu(x.mm(w1)).mm(w2)
loss = (y_pred - y).pow(2).sum()
loss.backward()
```

Output

```
ctx  (tensor([[-34.2381,  18.6334,   8.8368,  ...,  13.7337, -31.5657, -11.8838],
        [-25.5597,  -6.2847,   9.9412,  ..., -75.0621,   5.0451, -32.9348],
        [-56.6591, -40.0830,   2.4311,  ...,  -2.8988, -18.9742, -74.0132],
        ...,
        [ -6.4023, -30.3526, -73.9649,  ...,   1.8587, -23.9617, -11.6951],
        [ -3.6425,  34.5828,  27.7200,  ..., -34.3878, -19.7250,  11.1960],
        [ 16.0137, -24.0628,  14.4008,  ...,  -5.4443,   9.9499, -18.1259]],
       grad_fn=<MmBackward>),)
inputs  tensor([[-34.2381,  18.6334,   8.8368,  ...,  13.7337, -31.5657, -11.8838],
        [-25.5597,  -6.2847,   9.9412,  ..., -75.0621,   5.0451, -32.9348],
        [-56.6591, -40.0830,   2.4311,  ...,  -2.8988, -18.9742, -74.0132],
        ...,
        [ -6.4023, -30.3526, -73.9649,  ...,   1.8587, -23.9617, -11.6951],
        [ -3.6425,  34.5828,  27.7200,  ..., -34.3878, -19.7250,  11.1960],
        [ 16.0137, -24.0628,  14.4008,  ...,  -5.4443,   9.9499, -18.1259]],
       grad_fn=<MmBackward>)
```

Comment: The `,` is necessary because `(x)` is just `x`.

Comment: @tobias_k What is printed seems to be `(x,)`, which is different from `x`.

Comment: There is no "second half". A tuple is an immutable container that contains 0 or more elements. You create a tuple using the comma operator, with parentheses only necessary to distinguish a tuple-creating comma from other commas (e.g., the ones that separate function arguments: `f(2,3,4)` vs `f((2,3), 4)`) and as a special case the empty tuple which is *just* parentheses (since empty parentheses aren't otherwise a valid expression).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an edge-case of unpacking a single-element list or tuple.

```
a, = [1]
print(type(a), a)
# <class 'int'> 1
```

Without the comma, `a` would have been assigned the entire list:

```
a = [1]
print(type(a), a)
# <class 'list'> [1]
```

And the same goes for a tuple:

```
a, = (1,)  # have to use , with literal single-tuples, because (1) is just 1
print(type(a), a)
# <class 'int'> 1

a = (1,)  # have to use , with literal single-tuples, because (1) is just 1
print(type(a), a)
# <class 'tuple'> (1,)
```

Comment: I would use `(1,)` to better match the example. I also would not call this an edge case. It's just "a", case - quite the normal and expected behavior.

Comment: @kabanus ok, updated. But I still think it's an edge-case, as the trailing comma is not needed for anything else except single-element tuples

Comment: I see where you are coming from. What I meant is that if printing a single element tuple, this is what I would expect - the output to "look" like a tuple, a one-element one in this case.

Comment: @kabanus I agree about the output, but I believe that the premise of the question is the `,` on the assignment line, not in the output

Comment: Fair enough, that was just my perspective. You already have my vote :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I thought there might be another value in the tuple that was being discarded and didn't occur to me the tuple just had one value in it. Do you know why they have used a tuple if it only contains one tensor?

Comment: @EddyWD Probably to have a function that always returns a tuple instead of sometimes returning a tensor object and sometimes a tuples of tensor, it always returns a tuple of sensors. It just so happens that in this case there is a single tensor in the tuple

Answer (score 1):

(a, b) is a two-tuple, (a, b, c) is a three-tuple, (a, b, c,d) is a four-tuple.

Going the other way (a) would be a one-tuple. But that conflicts with e.g. `(1 + 2) / 3` because you can't divide a tuple. Since one-tuples are rare and parens in math expressions are common the `( <expr> )` is not a tuple. And extra trailing , is required, as in `(a, )`.

Note: (a, b, ) and (a, b, c, ) work too.

Same goes for unpacking tuples:

a, = tuple

unpacks the tuple and sets a to the first (and only) item.